# Java WeakHashMap reference not being updated

Tags: java, weak-references, weakhashmap

In the code below I create a Pen object and initialize it's color to white.  In the constructor of Pen, after setting the field 'penColor' to the value passed into the constructor, I update a global static weak hashmap that I'm keeping where the KEY is the 'this pointer - in my case a Pen, and the value is another weakhashmap whose KEY is the string "penColor" and whose value is a reference to the penColor member field.

Next, my code updates the Pen's color with a call to the Pen's setColor function.  I would have thought that after this update, if I looked up the Pen object's color field in my weakhashmap, it would reflect the new color, but it does not.  Can someone explain why that is?

```
package weakhashmaptest;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {

    static WeakHashMap <Object, WeakHashMap>ownerMap = new WeakHashMap<Object, WeakHashMap>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pen r = new Pen(Color.WHITE);

        Iterator i = ownerMap.keySet().iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Object key = i.next();
            System.out.println("\telement of hashmap is : " +ownerMap.get(key));
        }

        r.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        System.gc();

        i = ownerMap.keySet().iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Object key = i.next();
            System.out.println("\telement of hashmap is : " +ownerMap.get(key));
        }

    }

    public static void mapUpdate(Object owner, Object reference, String field_name) {

        WeakHashMap reference_map = ownerMap.get(owner);

        if (reference_map == null) {         
            reference_map = new WeakHashMap();
            reference_map.put(field_name, reference);
        } else {         
            reference_map.put(field_name, reference);
        }

        ownerMap.put(owner, reference_map);

    }

}

class Pen {

    Color penColor;

    public Pen(Color c) {

        penColor = c;
        Main.mapUpdate(this, penColor, "penColor");

    }

    public void setColor(Color c) {

        penColor = c;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're putting a reference to the *Color* object into the map, rather than the *Pen*. If you put the *Pen* into the map, and then asked for the pen's colour later on, you'd see the change.

To put it in very simplistic terms, what you're doing is similar to:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.WHITE);
Color color = pen.penColor;
pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
// color here still refers to Color.WHITE, not Color.BLACK.
```

Comment: Hi John,

   Thanks for the prompt response.  I think I understand what you're saying, but it still is hard to digest.  How is the Pen color different than the Pen.  Aren't they both references?  Notice I am keeping the Pen in the map, as a KEY.

Comment: You're keeping the Pen as the key, but you're using the *initial colour* as the value. It's just a reference to an object - it's not a reference to the expression "this.penColor" or anything like that.

Comment: Should I take your acceptance as understanding? If not, please do add more comments and we can go through this as much as you like. I think it's worth taking out the nested maps from the equation though - they're not really relevant, but they may be making it harder for you to think about.

Comment: I know you're right because when I update my example with your suggestion it works.  I'm trying to achieve the following:
I'm doing bytecode instrumentation inside of the constructor of an object.  After each field is initialized, I update a weak hashmap that says : The owner object is 'this', and it's value is another hashmap whose key is the name of the field, and whose value is a reference to the field.
Now, I would have hoped that what this buys me is the following :  When the references are updated, I don't have to do more BCI, I can rely on the maps pointer to the reference.

Comment: I was limited to 600 characters in my last message, so I had to be super concise.  I'm not asking you to solve this problem for me, simply to explain if my approach is feasable, and if not, why.  I guess I'm confused on references and pointers here...

Comment: OK, if I accept this statement by you : 'it's not a reference to the expression "this.penColor" or anything like that', then I completely understand.  The question then is, is it possible to get a reference to "this.penColor".

Comment: Basically you'd have to store a reference to the Pen (which you already have) and find out the current field value with reflection. It'll be ugly, I'm afraid.

Comment: That was my suspicion as well.  Thanks for taking the time to clarify this for me.